# AVCapturePhotoOutput orientation cannot be changed on ios

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I am using ios 11, swift 4 and  capturing a picture with av foundation library. I have a custom preview as shown and mysettings are as suggested. The problem is when I capture and save the CMSample buffer, it is leftLandscape oriented. I tried to change CapturePhotoOutput orientation but it resist to change?(changing photoOutputConnection.videoOrientation changes nothing?)

```
if let photoOutputConnection = capturePhotoOutput.connection(with: AVMediaType.video) {

    if(photoOutputConnection.isVideoOrientationSupported)   {
        print("video oryantasyonu = \(photoOutputConnection.videoOrientation)")
    } else {
        print("video oryantasyonu desteklenmiyor ?!")
    }
}
```

Here is the preview (phono screen):
[image: preview on iphone SE]

and here is the capture output taken from xcode debug quick view:

[image]

Here is session configuration :

```
self.capturePhotoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()

capturePhotoOutput.isHighResolutionCaptureEnabled = true

//  A Live Photo captures both a still image and a short movie centered on the moment of capture,

//  which are presented together in user interfaces such as the Photos app.

capturePhotoOutput.isLivePhotoCaptureEnabled = capturePhotoOutput.isLivePhotoCaptureSupported

guard self.captureSession.canAddOutput(capturePhotoOutput) else { return }

//  The sessionPreset property of the capture session defines the resolution and quality level of the video output.

//  For most photo capture purposes, it is best set to AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto to deliver high resolution photo quality output.

self.captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo

self.captureSession.addOutput(capturePhotoOutput)

self.captureSession.commitConfiguration()
```

Comment: Where are you getting the CMSampleBuffer from? Is this AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate.captureOutput()?

Comment: No, I am using the AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate ?

Comment: Don’t have code in front of me but I seem to remember photoOutputConnection.videoOrientation should work. Have you tried the iOS 11 function with the AVCapturePhotoOutput as a parameter. The CMSampleBuffer version is deprecated.

Comment: Yes I am  already using AvCapturePhotoOutput. I will come back to this issue later, I have found a workaround for now(not a solution), and let you know if I solve it.